# Show image in other div using mouseover

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script that shows onmouseover the image in a bigger box.
But, after 3 days working.. It's still not working.

So, i have 1/4 tiny images, and when i use a mousover the image src of the bigger image should been updated.

My codes,

JS

```
function newImage(link)
        {
            document.getElementById("imageshow").src=link;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="itemimage">
                        <img src="/images/items/0abdc563a06105aee3c6136871c9f4d1.jpeg" name="imageshow" id="imageshow" width="250"/> // big image
                    </div>
                    <div id="litemimage">
                        <img src="/images/items/0abdc563a06105aee3c6136871c9f4d1.jpeg" onmouseover="newImage('/images/items/0abdc563a06105aee3c6136871c9f4d1.jpeg')" width="100"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="litemimage">
                        <img src="/images/items/46f5ffb3777b7659bb35da6ddab19e05.png" onmouseover="newImage(this.src)" width="100"/>
                    </div><div id="litemimage">
                        <img src="/images/items/44feb0096faa8326192570788b38c1d1.png" onmouseover="newImage('/images/items/44feb0096faa8326192570788b38c1d1.png')" width="100"/>
                    </div><div id="litemimage">
                        <img src="/images/items/2d45cbe914655ca562553cb81fdfc464.jpeg" onmouseover="newImage('/images/items/2d45cbe914655ca562553cb81fdfc464.jpeg')" width="100"/>
                    </div>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: id should not be used multiple times. it should be unique in the page

Comment: you're getting the src of the image and replacing src skin that was there so that the image is not changing

Comment: So you say, first hide, replace and then show it again?

Comment: check i have answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html:**

```
<div class="largeView">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNh6K8kjBSaLwzCmaGHb2HFREfIQR6THrneqDc20mtJHUIXBdkeQ" name="imageshow" id="imageshow" width="250"/> 
</div>
<div class="litemimage">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNh6K8kjBSaLwzCmaGHb2HFREfIQR6THrneqDc20mtJHUIXBdkeQ" onmouseover="newImage('http://commun-it.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Big-Picture-Mountains-credit-blimiers2.jpg')" width="50"/>
</div>
<div class="litemimage">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQopJbH0D5IlIYQwQ3iBL4RnA4Dqk0s8csW-jZnfhF6twUuceA0" onmouseover="newImage('http://www.flagstaffbusinessnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Picture-Canyon-.jpg')" width="50"/>
</div>
<div class="litemimage">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNh6K8kjBSaLwzCmaGHb2HFREfIQR6THrneqDc20mtJHUIXBdkeQ" onmouseover="newImage(this.src)" width="50"/>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
<script>
    function newImage(src) {
        document.getElementById("imageshow").src = src;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: keep in mind id means unique. it should never be repeated in a page. classes can be multiple. css will work with multiple ids with same name but javascript will break

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KuP2d/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="largeView">
    <img id="imageshow" src="placeholder.jpg">
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
    <div class="litemimage">
        <img src="small1.jpg" data-large="large1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="litemimage">
        <img src="small2.jpg" data-large="large2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="litemimage">
        <img src="small3.jpg" data-large="large3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="litemimage">
        <img src="small4.jpg" data-large="large4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
thumbs.onmouseover = function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName=="IMG"){
        imageshow.src = e.target.getAttribute("data-large");
    }
}
```

Comment: It doens't work for me.
Is it a problem if every image has his own div?

Comment: @user3194432 It doesn't matter, but you can always change the event to handle it